# NPM: How to get bumped version in my CLI command?

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning, npm-scripts, npm-version

Let's say i have a library and when i compile it with webpack i also add a banner such as this one: `// LibraryName vX.X` where `vX.X` is its version.

I want to compile it with npm `preversion` script. As here:

`"preversion": "gulp build --version MYVERSION"`

Where `MYVERSION` is a semver version that will appear in `package.json` **after calling `npm version`**.

How can i get that `MYVERSION` from CLI command?

**EDIT**

I know i can simply get version from `package.json` if i run it with `postversion`, but i want build be before adding a git tag.

Answer (score 0):

Closing this question, because i found the answer.

**TL;DR** The answer is: Use `version` instead of `preversion` in npm-scripts.

You can found more details [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version) in explanation of scripts order.

> Run the `version` script. These scripts have access to the new version in `package.json`